# How To Change Every Other Value in An Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

For this programming assignment, my professor wants us to replace every other number in this array into a 100 using a for loop:

```
//-- (8) Use the array called grades, below.
//--     starting with index 0 use a for loop to change every other 
//--     grade to 100.
//--     Printf what the array was BEFORE the changes, and AFTER then Changes.

int i;
int g;
int grades[] = { 87, 95, 65, 70, 77, 99, 0, 65, 25, 80, 90, 11 };
System.out.println ("\n(8) Before change: " + Arrays.toString(grades)); 
for (i = 0; i < grades.length; ++i)
  {
  //FIXME: For every other grade (index 0, 2, 4, 6, 8), change grade to 100
   
  }
 System.out.println ("\n(8) After change:" + Arrays.toString(grades));
```

However, I am not sure how to do this. I have tried something like this: grade[0] = 100; grade[2] = 100; etc., but my professor wants us to pretend the program doesn't know that we put in those numbers for the array (if that makes sense). I appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could even use the modulo operator

```
for (i = 0; i < grades.length; ++i)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      grades[i] = 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by playing with the `for` loop arguments:

```
for (i = 0; i < grades.length; i+=2) {
   grades[i]=100;
}
```

So here, after each iteration, you will increment `i` by `2` by using `i+=2` instead of `i++`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop. Increment by 2 instead of by 1. For example,

```
for (i = 0; i < grades.length; i += 2)
{
    grades[i] = 100;
}
```

Or, if you can't change `++i` just

```
for (i = 0; i < grades.length; ++i)
{
    grades[i] = 100;
    ++i;
}
```

or

```
for (i = 0; i < grades.length; ++i)
{
    grades[i++] = 100;
}
```